# "self-contained"

Tags: phrase-usage

My own little understanding on the phrase "self-contained" is simply independent. But of late I wonder sometimes whether this term has some derogatory meaning in everyday English? For instance, will calling some kid self-contained imply implying him somewhat arrogant?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct in that 'self-contained' means an independent, complete unit. However, it is not applied to describe people in a derogatory sense. A similar phrase that fulfils that role might be 'self-absorbed'.